# Oracle Forms comparing two checkboxes status

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

I have a form that has two checkboxes, one is dup and one is sum.  They both take values, add them up, and display the total in a display item. I have that part covered in an if statement on both checkboxes.  What I need some assistance with, is a third if statement that, if sum is checked and the user checks dup, oracle forms pops up a message, uncheck the dup checkbox, and does nothing else.  Here is the code I have so far :

```
IF    :mn_outstanding_trans.cb_duplicate_activity ='Y' THEN
   :mn_outstanding_trans.activity_cd := 'SUM';
   :bl_control.gross_sum_of_trxs :=   :bl_control.gross_sum_of_trxs + :mn_outstanding_trans.gross_amt;
   :bl_control.net_sum_of_trxs :=  :bl_control.net_sum_of_trxs + :mn_outstanding_trans.net_amt;
   :bl_control.previous_activity_cd := :mn_outstanding_trans.activity_cd;     
ELSIF :mn_outstanding_trans.cb_duplicate_activity ='N' THEN
   :mn_outstanding_trans.activity_cd := ' ';
   :bl_control.gross_sum_of_trxs :=   :bl_control.gross_sum_of_trxs - :mn_outstanding_trans.gross_amt;
   :bl_control.net_sum_of_trxs :=  :bl_control.net_sum_of_trxs - :mn_outstanding_trans.net_amt;
   :bl_control.previous_activity_cd := :mn_outstanding_trans.activity_cd;    
END IF;
```

Answer (score 2):

> if sum is checked and the user checks dup, oracle forms pops up a message, uncheck the dup checkbox

It seems that you want to allow either DUP or SUM checkbox set, but never both. If that's so, then you should use a **radio button** instead of two checkboxes (which are supposed to exclude each other).

---

Also, maybe it would be easier to understand what you're talking about if you posted a screenshot of that form.